# Showing x object in an array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My app has a set of 'players' with their own attributes which I want to display in a modal window and cycle through. The UI is as follows

```
 <!-- Score Round Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myScoreModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" ng-repeat="player in players">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Score for {{player.data}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="cancelRound()">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="previousPlayer()">Previous</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="nextPlayer()">Next Player</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="calculateRound()">Finish</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Where I want the player (and later some attributes) to display I can get the first name to display. But I want to cycle using the functions `previousPlayer()` and `nextPlayer()`. The `js` section has a variable that I increase and decrease called `currentPlayer` like so:

```
$scope.nextPlayer = function () {
    // Cycles to next player cards within the round
    $scope.currentPlayer++;
    console.log($scope.currentPlayer);
};


$scope.previousPlayer = function () {
    // Cycle to previous player cards within the round
    $scope.currentPlayer--;
    console.log($scope.currentPlayer);
};
```

The goal would be to be able to not just view, but also modify the `player` model.

Comment: `ng-repeat="player in players"` to replace with `ng-repeat="player in players track by $index"` , then you can do an `ng-if="(condition on $index)"` . $index = the index used in the 'players' array. Another way is to create another array called players_in_cycle and to swap places in it.

Comment: so `ng-if="(currentPlayer = $index)"` feels like the expression, but where would I place that exactly?

Comment: What is expected behavior? Seems like you only need one modal and toggle the data shown. What modal library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to display player data for 1 player at a time, so one modal window ought to be enough.

Your HTML can be simplified a bit - you don't need to use `ng-repeat` and `ng-if`: access the current player with `players[currentPlayer]` instead:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myScoreModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Score for {{players[currentPlayer ].data}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="cancelRound()">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" ng-if="currentPlayer > 0" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="previousPlayer()">Previous</button>
          <button type="button" ng-if="currentPlayer < players.length - 1" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="nextPlayer()">Next Player</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="calculateRound()">Finish</button>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Working JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kxUR9/16/

Comment: I made some adjustments to the UI but this works marvels. This may be a bit out of context but in the "..." section is where the scoring happens. I take it that all I need to do is add something like `ng-model="players[currentPlayer].someScoreElement"` to tie it into that player, correct?

Answer (score -1):

If you only want one player displayed then using `ng-repeat` doesn't make sense.

Just set a new property `$scope.player`

```
$scope.currentPlayer = 0;

function setPlayer() {
  if ($scope.currentPlayer >= 0 && $scope.currentPlayer < $scope.players.length) {
    $scope.player = $scope.players[$scope.currentPlayer];
  }else{
    alert('At end of players');
  }
}

setPlayer();

$scope.nextPlayer = function() {
  // Cycles to next player cards within the round
  $scope.currentPlayer++;
  setPlayer();

};
$scope.previousPlayer = function() {
  // Cycle to previous player cards within the round
  $scope.currentPlayer--;
  setPlayer();
};
```

In the view just remove the `ng-repeat`